# How to Install LAMP on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lamp

Amazon 7*24 online support has been so good that why Amazon EC2 has been selected as one of the most common website hosting service, like Magento store.

But AWS EC2 is not as easy as cPanel! That's why I maintain and share my updated experiences in here!

Answer (score -1):

We use Amazon Lunix because we believe we can get a better support from Amazon

This Tutorial has been always updated by Amazon and very helpful
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Here is just a summary of all steps, for details for above Amazon on-line tutorial

https://github.com/johnjyin/Install-LAMP-Magento-on-AWS-EC2/blob/master/Install%20LAMP%20on%20AWS%20EC2.txt